# Refreshing WooCommerce Shortcode on AJAX Add-to-Cart

Tags: php, ajax, woocommerce, cart, shortcode

I created a custom shortcode to display the current quantity of a particular product that is in the customer's cart. The shortcode works great, but is only updated when the page is refreshed. I'm trying to get it work with AJAX.

I know there are a ton of questions on here related to WooCommerce AJAX and the add_to_cart_fragments filter hook, but I've so far been unable to find a solution for getting a simple shortcode (or the container in which the shortcode is placed) to update on AJAX.

Here's the code that I currently have, but I'm still quite a novice and I must be doing something wrong with the way I'm using woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
// Create the shortcode

if( ! function_exists('get_product_quantity_in_cart') ) {
    function get_product_quantity_in_cart( $atts ) {
        
        // Extract shortcode attributes
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'id' => '',
        ), $atts, 'cart_qty_badge' ) );
        
        if( empty($id) || WC()->cart->is_empty() ) return; 

        $total_qty = 0; 
        
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if( $cart_item['product_id'] == $id ) {
                $total_qty += $cart_item['quantity'];
            }
        }
        return $total_qty > 0 ? $total_qty : '';
    }
    add_shortcode( 'cart_qty_badge', 'get_product_quantity_in_cart' );
}

// Refresh shortcode on AJAX add-to-cart
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'refresh_cart_count' );

function refresh_cart_count ( $fragments ){
    
    $fragments['#cart_qty_badge'] = get_product_quantity_in_cart();
    return $fragments;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can't work as your specific product ID is missing in:

```php
$fragments['#cart_qty_badge'] = get_product_quantity_in_cart();
```

You need to replace that line with the following, using `do_shortcode()` function and your complete shortcode that include the `id` argument for your specific product ID, like:

```php
$fragments['#cart_qty_badge'] = do_shortcode('[cart_qty_badge id="23"]');
```

where `23` is your targeted specific product ID...

It should work now.